# Solution to $x\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ such that $1^Tx=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I am looking at part of a problem where the following conditions exist: let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ such that $1^Tx=1$, where $1^T$ I am pretty sure is just a vector of length $n$, filled with ones.

My thought that because $x>0$, that there is no $x$ values that satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions are all and only the vectors
$$
x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\;\;\mbox{with}\;\;x_i>0\;\;\forall i
$$
such that
$$
x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n=1.
$$

It is clear that $x_i<1$ for all $i$. The solutions are infinite.

Take for example the case $n=2$; one you fix any $x_1\in(0,1)$, just consider $x_2=1-x_1$. Then it is clear that the vector $(x_1,x_2)$ does the job, and it is clear as well that there exists infinitely many of it (as many as the choices of $x_1\in(0,1)$).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that  $x_i = \frac1n, i=1, \ldots, n$ is a solution.

Example: $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \frac12 \\ \frac12 \end{bmatrix} = 1$

The corresponding region is a simplex without the boundary.

Comment: oh, I see, its a hyperplane with a gradient of 1, truncated in the positive orthant